# Emacs cannot find virtual drive defined by MS Windows command `subst`

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, find-file

I am using spacemacs (0.200.13@26.1), but this should be applicable to vanilla Emacs too. The version of Emacs I'm experiencing this issue on is "GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30".
I created a virtual drive in windows, using the `subst` MS Windows command. Something like this:

```
w: subst c:/users/me/projects
```

Then, I open Emacs and try to access this drive. I fail to do so and the only information I get back is.

> The system cannot find the drive specified.

How to solve this? Can I even use virtual drives in Emacs?

Comment: Which Emacs are you running? Examples are: the [mingw built](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#windows), [Emacs under cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Femacs-X11%2Femacs-X11-26.2-1&grep=Emacs), [Emacs under WSL](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/emacs) I think the output of `M-x emacs-version` would be informative enough.

Comment: @Tobias Added the version information to the main post.

Comment: `subst i: c:\temp` on `cmd.exe` and `find-file i:\test.txt` in Emacs afterwards work for me in `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, i686-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30`.

Comment: I'm sorry for mess. It seems to work for me too... I don't know what did I do to fix it, but needless to say, I'm happy it works. Thank you for help! I cannot give you any points tho :/